# Diacritic chars encoding in API requests

Tags: api, encoding, mocha.js, supertest

I have one question about encoding diacritic chars in API request.

I can send via postman request `GET /rest/city?query=Poznań`, response is correct, in server logs city?query=Poznań is changed to `city?query=Pozna%C5%84`.

Also I have API test written in node.js (mocha, supertest) and here request `GET /rest/city?query=Poznań` return empty array, in server logs request method changed to `GET /rest/city?query=PoznaD`.

What's wrong with encoding in my API auto tests? Why ń changed to D?
Do You know how can I changed this to fix issue.

Also in logs `city?query=Łódz` changes in changes in `city?query=Aódz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have solution, just `city?query=${encodeURI(Łódź)}`